# Custom warning in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm working on an API library and I'd like to add a few warnings that would appear when another developers builds the app if an optional apikey is not included.  It should be buildable w/o the key (since it's optional) so I can't just add a syntax error to force a build error.

I know Xcode supports TODO and FIXME but those aren't really highlighted anywhere major.

Any other thoughts on how to approach this?

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `#warning` preprocessor directive:

```
#warning This will appear in the compiler warnings output
```

The text following `#warning` will appear as a warning during compilation, but it won't prevent the project from being built (unless warnings are treated as errors).