# Swift Compiler Macro (Warn or Stop There)

Tags: swift

Are there any compiler macro's which can be used with Swift? Often enough, I use templates regularly which regularly need quite a few sections altering and since moving to swift, I've lose the love of `#warning`

Comment: Do you mean macros or directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do to use `// MARK`:

```
// MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    if let backgroundImageChangedBlock = self.backgroundImageChangedBlock {
        backgroundImageChangedBlock(backgroundImage: image)
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate Methods
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .None)
}
```

[image]

Xcode not supports `#warning`, but you can to use script phrase:https://stackoverflow.com/a/26869489/907422:

Add a new Run Script to your target's build phases tab (project settings > build phases > '+' > new run script phase), and paste the following code in the empty box:

```
TAGS="WARNING"
echo "searching ${SRCROOT} for ${TAGS}"
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($TAGS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($TAGS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's not what I was hoping to hear, but I guess after a day of searching, I was trying to avoid using scripts, but it seems the only way out other than a custom Xcode plugin...

Comment: @AdrianSluyters It is not a good solution, but it works.. Please tell me if you know a better way...

Answer (score 0):

There are no compiler macros or other [preprocessor directives](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_20) in Swift. You can set build configurations but I suspect this is not what you are looking for.

What you can do is to use [documentation](http://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/) to mark code sections as needing changes. You can also write unit tests that will fail unless your template is correctly implemented.

[Assertions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID335) might also be a good way to have templated code fail unless it is implemented properly.

Comment: I disagree as there are quite a few undocumented directives... I've just stumped across a few by disassembling swift, see this site (translated) for some others that people have come across: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fandelf.github.io%2Fblog%2F2014%2F06%2F06%2Fswift-attributes%2F&edit-text=&act=url

Comment: @AdrianSluyters Yes, there are [undocumented internal functions](http://www.russbishop.net/swift-don-t-do-this) that you probably should avoid using. They may change without warning or have unintended side effects.

Comment: I purely use them for my internal templates, so I'm not too fussed about them changing. I'd prefer a list of "warnings" that a full blown "halt" at compile time (or ominous bugs due to unfulfilled requirements.