# User created warnings no longer working in XCode 7.1. Is there an alternative?

Tags: c, xcode, swift, xcode7

Unfortunately the user-created warning pragma`#warning` no longer works for me in Xcode 7.1.

[image]

Are these `#` prefixed commands only in Objective-C Foundation Headers? Is there another way to specify them, or is it possible to use them with a bridging header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use `#warning` in Swift. This doesn't work, `#warning` is only compatible with Objective-C. The only thing that comes to mind is a comment or the things that are listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183812/swift-warning-equivalent), such as the answer from inerrupt:

> So what I do is declare FIXME() function in Swift file:

```
@availability(iOS, deprecated=1.0, message="I'm not deprecated, please ***FIXME**")
func FIXME()
{
}
```

> and when I call it from any other function it does show a warning, e.g.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    FIXME()     // Incomplete method implementation.
    return 0
}
```

> For Swift 2 use

```
@available(iOS, deprecated=1.0, message="I'm not deprecated, please ***FIXME**")
```

Comment: //FIXME: and //TODO: will do the work meanwhile...