# Can -Werror be disabled on a per-warning basis?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'd like to have warnings appear as errors for all warnings except one class of warnings. Is it possible to suppress `-Werror` for the one class of warnings?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235598/treat-some-warnings-as-errors-in-swift

Comment: @MikeTaverne definitely answers that question.