# Is there a way to generate a runtime warning that Xcode 8 can pick up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

I would like what `#warning message` does for build-time errors but for Xcode 8's new runtime errors.
To be clear, I'm not interested in just printing a warning with NSLog or compile-time warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: #warning equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183812/swift-warning-equivalent)

Comment: Not a duplicate, runtime != compiletime

Comment: It would be nice ... but the point of #warning messages is that they are compiler warnings, not run time warnings. You don't get debug build log messages while running, rather you only see debugger log messages.

Comment: But Xcode does generate runtime warnings (they are purple instead of the yellow compile time warnings), for example when you try to modify a view from a background thread.